# routing error for nested resource with ledermann-rails-settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rubygems, settings

I'm trying to allow users to update preferences from default settings with a form for [ledermann-rails-settings](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings).  I got the form built based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492155/form-for-and-ledermann-rails-settings?lq=1), but when I try to submit the form to update settings, I get a routing error that I think is related to nested resources, but I'm new to RoR so I'm not sure.  Other questions about this on SO appear to use Rails 3 or a previous version of the gem.  I'm using rails 4.2.1.

routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  resources :settings
end
```

rake routes:

```
      user_settings GET    /users/:user_id/settings(.:format)          settings#index
                    POST   /users/:user_id/settings(.:format)          settings#create
   new_user_setting GET    /users/:user_id/settings/new(.:format)      settings#new
  edit_user_setting GET    /users/:user_id/settings/:id/edit(.:format) settings#edit
       user_setting GET    /users/:user_id/settings/:id(.:format)      settings#show
                    PATCH  /users/:user_id/settings/:id(.:format)      settings#update
                    PUT    /users/:user_id/settings/:id(.:format)      settings#update
                    DELETE /users/:user_id/settings/:id(.:format)      settings#destroy
              users GET    /users(.:format)                            users#index
                    POST   /users(.:format)                            users#create
           new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                        users#new
          edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                   users#edit
               user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#show
                    PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                    PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                    DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                        users#destroy
```

the form:

```
<%= form_for(:settings) do |form| %>
<h3>Dashboard settings</h3>
  <%= form.fields_for :dashboard, current_user.settings(:dashboard) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :theme_light, 'Light (Default)' %>
      <%= f.radio_button :theme, "themes/flatly" %>
      <%= f.label :theme_dark, 'Dark' %>
      <%= f.radio_button :theme, "themes/darkly" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

SettingsController:

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    if params[:settings]
      params[:settings].each do |key, value|
        current_user.settings(key.to_sym).update_attributes! value
      end
      flash[:success] = "Settings updated!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

User.rb:

```
has_settings do |s|
  s.key :dashboard, :defaults => { :theme => 'themes/flatly' }
end
```

Submitting the form as-is right now gives the following routing error:

> Started POST "/users/1/settings/1/edit" for 72.231.138.82 at 2016-07-01 15:12:36 +0000
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/1/settings/1/edit")

I think I understand the Rails Guides for nested resource forms to mean that the first line of the form should be something like

```
<%= form_for([@user, @settings]) do |form| %>
```

but changing that gives the error

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Additionally, ledermann-rails-settings doesn't appear to have a method for calling all settings (at least so far as I can tell on the current version of the gem), so I'm not sure how I would even define @settings.

I've tried specifying different paths in the form with no luck, as well as trying resource: setting and resources: settings in routes.rb.  I feel like I'm missing something at either the controller or routes level, but I don't have enough experience to know where and the gem docs and issues don't have much on forms.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone else, here's how I got this working.

```
<%= form_for(:settings, url: user_setting_path, html: { method: :put }) do |form| %>
```

SettingsController

```
def update
  if setting_params
    setting_params.each do |key, value|
      @current_user.settings(key.to_sym).update_attributes! value
    end
    flash[:success] = "Settings updated!"
    redirect_to request.referrer
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def setting_params
  params.require(:settings).permit(dashboard: :theme)
end
```

Comment: Helped me a lot. Thanks!